# Creating text table from Impala partitioned parquet table

Tags: hive, impala, parquet

I have a parquet table formatted as follows:

```
.impala_insert_staging
yearmonth=2013-04
yearmonth=2013-05
yearmonth=2013-06
...
yearmonth=2016-04
```

Underneath each of these directories are my parquet files.  I need to get them into my another table which just has a

```
.impala_insert_staging
```

file.

Please help.

Comment: I really, really don't understand what is the issue. Why don't you run a simple query such as `INSERT INTO TABLE target SELECT cola, colb, ... FROM source` and use Impala for what it is, i.e. a database engine?

Answer (score 0):

The best I found is to pull the files in locally and `sqoop` them back up into a text table.

To pull the parquet table down I performed the following:

```
impala-shell -i <ip-addr> -B -q "use default; select * from <table>" -o filename '--output_delimiter=\x1A'
```

Unfortunately this adds the `yearmonth` value as another column on my table.  So I either go into my 750GB file and `sed/awk` out that last column or use `mysqlimport` (since I'm using MySQL as well) to import only the columns I'm interested in.

Finally I'll sqoop up the data to a new text table.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysqlip> --table <mysql_table> -uroot -p<pass> --hive-import --hive-table <new_db_text>
```